# Why returning MemoryStream sets the position on end

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I noticed that returning MemoryStream will reset its position to the "last" position. Why is that?

When I was testing this in the working method, before returning I explicitly set position to 0

```
myStream.position = 0; // I allso tried myStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

But when checking the position in both instances the position was not set to 0.

Edit (thought this was a more theoretical question so I didn't bother adding all the code but here goes)

```
public MemoryStream GenerateOpenXmlFileAsStrem()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    // Here the data gets inserted into the DataTable

    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream;
}
```

And then I tried to test the method

```
[Test]
public Task GenerateOpenXmlFileAsStremTest()
{
    using (Context context = new Context (_options))
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    using (Context context = new Context (_options))
    {
        _target = new Service(_mapper, _mockedLogger.Object, _dbContext, _mockedNotificationService.Object);
        MemoryStream result = _target.GenerateOpenXmlFileAsStrem();

        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal(0, result.Position); // somehow this is not true
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever something reads from (or writes to) the stream, the position changes. In a normal method if you `return` the stream, nothing happens to it, but a method controlled by asp.net could read from the stream to access its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SpreadsheetDocument writes to the Stream on Dispose it would cause that result.  Try explicitly calling Flush/Close/Dispose before repositioning the Stream, eg:

```
document.Dispose();
memoryStream.Position = 0;
return memoryStream;
```

Comment: `Flush` is overridden for `MemoryStream`. It does nothing.

Comment: It’s the Document writing to the MemoryStream that may need to be Disposed or Closed to write the last bytes to the Stream.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know Dispose forced a flush. Glad it does.